# No recent Ubuntu 18 updates?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt-get

Seems I would normally see something in a week, but now, nothing in 2. When I run `sudo apt-get update`, what I get is:

```
sudo apt-get update
Ign:1 http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge InRelease
Ign:2 https://dl.bintray.com/openhab/apt-repo2 stable InRelease
Hit:3 http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge Release
Get:4 https://dl.bintray.com/openhab/apt-repo2 stable Release [6,051 B]
Hit:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:7 https://downloads.plex.tv/repo/deb public InRelease
Hit:8 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]
Hit:10 http://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease
Hit:12 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Get:13 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [83.2 kB]
Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Err:5 http://www.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 143.95.32.90 80]
Get:16 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]
Get:17 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [245 kB]
Get:18 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons [55.7 kB]
Get:19 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons [105 kB]
Get:20 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [200 kB]
Get:21 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [178 kB]
Get:22 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [204 B]
Get:23 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [329 kB]
Get:24 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,464 B]
Get:25 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [5,808 B]
Get:26 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [14.9 kB]
Get:27 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [9,088 B]
Get:28 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [39.7 kB]
Reading package lists...
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/dists/xenial-getdeb/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 143.95.32.90 80]
E: The repository 'http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu xenial-getdeb InRelease' is not signed.
W: Conflicting distribution: https://downloads.plex.tv/repo/deb public InRelease (expected public but got )
```

Not sure why am getting that forbidden shown. What looks wrong here or has there just not been any update recently cause of the holidays?

Comment: There's no Ubuntu 18. It's either 18.04, the current LTS release supported until 2023 or 18.10 that shouldn't be used now because EOL, unsupported.

Answer (score 0):

GetDeb has been down for several weeks now. It is presumed abandoned. check [HERE](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/672628)

so it is recommended to delete all references to getdeb.net from your package management system.

and for the conflict `sudo apt clean-all` and then `sudo apt update` might fix the problem. there might be some signature problems as well that can be fixed by adding new signatures via `curl`.

and other packages, well there is no update for them. for new year holidays no one was working :D probably.